# "There was an error parsing the query. SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I wrote an little app in C# to keep track of customers and jobs but I get an error

> "There was an error parsing the query.[Token line number = 1, Token
>   line offset = 14,Token in error = ']

I'm using a SQL Server CE `.sdf` database

```
    public static void CreateEmployeeTable(string name)
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE `@Name` (
                                `Id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                `Job` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                                `Pay` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                                `TotalJobs` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                                `TotalPay` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

I researched the error a lot and seems this error is pretty vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot parameterise a `CREATE` table statement that way.

Simply construct the `CommandText` string in code using string concatenation (being careful of possible SQL Injection vulnerabilities) and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parameterize the table name in your example.  I altered your create table SQL to conform to supported data types for SQL CE.  Please note that the NVARCHAR statements are set to a length of 100 to support up to the 50 characters you were specifying (VARCHAR is not supported).

I tested this code sample, but there are a couple more things to think about:

1. Your method is currently public.  I don't know the context in which you are calling this, but consider making it private or internal.
2. Consider querying first to determine whether the table already exists to avoid an exception.
3. If at all possible I would create the connection in a using block directly above your command creation.  That way you will know the connection gets closed and disposed.  I'll leave that to your discretion.

   ```
   public static void CreateEmployeeTable(string name)
   {
       const string createTableFormat = @"CREATE TABLE [{0}] ( 
                          Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                          Job NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
                          Pay NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
                          TotalJobs NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
                          TotalPay NVARCHAR(100) NULL)";
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
       }

       // Just replace with your connection string.
       using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(Settings.Default.LocalDbConnectionString))                       
       using (SqlCeCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
       {                    
           cmd.CommandText = string.Format(createTableFormat, name);
           cn.Open();         
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       }            
   }
   ```